# PHP regex get from string

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have this string:

```
I like bacon but nothing else
```

How would I extract "bacon" from the string?
Like also this one:

```
I like jerking around
```

And that one would only get jerking?

Thanks! :)

Would this envolve regex maybe??

Comment: So you want to find the 3rd word? Will all strings begin with "I like"

Comment: Bacon and jerking. What you get upto behind closed doors is your business.

Comment: Sure, or if it's always the third word you could: split the string and get the third part of the array or find the second and third space and use substr to grab that word..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "I like bacon but nothing else";
$word = end(explode(" ", $string, 3));
echo $word;
```

This will get your third word from string.